# Starting java application while tomcat starts

Tags: java, watchservice, servletcontextlistener

I want to start a watchservice application while starting tomcat.I am doing this by using listener in web.xml. As expected watch service run successfully. but after that tomcat doesn't start.Watch key take control of that.How to start watchservice while starting application.????

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Code and configuration files please